# My questions is about using Swiper http://idangero.us, with ionic 4

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic4, swiper.js

I set Swiper by installing it in the cli. The css styling works fine but the functionality(sliding) is missing. When i try to follow the source code there is this object declared as "new Swiper" but i cannot find the "*Swiper*". How do i access this Swiper type and use it with my DOM elements.

I tried importing the Swiper Class from swiper which does not seem to be a problem. The problem starts when i set a custom object as that Swiper i imported. It gives me an error saying "export '*Swiper*' was not found in 'swiper'". I tried:

```
// Importing the swiper class
import {Swiper} from 'swiper';

// creating the object
  const swipes = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
```

I just need the slides to function as the demo shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to install swiper into Ionic4 - it's built in.

Look up the `ion-slides` [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides) and you will see extensive code examples about how you can customise it and use it in Ionic.

Comment: If it helps then please consider upvoting or marking as answer.

Comment: I downgraded my app to v3 in order to use them, everything is fine now. Thanks